# What does the signal-level in my router settings mean?

Tags: dsl, dsl-modem

I've looked up DSL information of my Speedport Smart and I found the point "Signal-level" with the values -17 for Upstream and 136 for Downstream. What exactly does "Signal-level" mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you [edit] to provide a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the signal level numbers should have a `-` ... anything else is "rubbish".

*Additional note: The measurements done by the router might not be that precise. Take them with a grain of salt.*

Generally:
The less negative the number, the stronger the signal is.

The stronger the signal is, the less likely it is you'll have a problem with the signal (assuming that the receiver or transmitter doesn't get saturated - i.e. is getting/creating a too strong signal).

The measurement unit is "dBm" - i.e "decibel related to one milliwatt" (0.001W).
A difference of 3dBm means half (or double, if higher) the signal strength.

-100dBm might be considered a low (weak) signal, if it is "too low" depends on the situation though.

Technical reference, much more detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm